# Magento 2 cannot override 3rd party controller

Tags: magento2, dependency-injection, preference

Im trying to override a controller from swissup/firecheckout location in my vendor folder

my di.xml is

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Swissup\FieldManager\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Save"
                type="My\Module\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Save" />
</config>
```

and my controller is

```
namespace My\Module\Controller\Adminhtml\Index;

class Save extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
    public function execute()
    {
        die('sample die');
    }
}
```

but its still executing in Swissup\FieldManager\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Save execute function. ive been debugging this one for quite some time now and dont know why its not working. i tried both etc/di.xml and etc/adminhtml/di.xml

Comment: Check modules `My_Module` enabled or not?

Answer (score 0):

Try with below code, it should extend the class for which preference is defined

```
<?php

namespace My\Module\Rewrite\Swissup\FieldManager\Controller\Adminhtml\Index;

class Save extends \Swissup\FieldManager\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Save
{
    public function execute()
    {
        die('sample die');
    }
}
```